# Почему в rx коллбэк выполняется много раз, а в angular 1 раз?

Tags: javascript, angular2, rxjs

Решил сравнить как я, не думая что происходит "под капотом", работал до сих пор с Observable в angular2 с реализацией Observable на нативном JS. В результате получил некторое несоответствие, о котором хотел бы сейчас спросить.

Вот как я понимаю Observable в простейшей реализации на нативном javascript:

```
class Observable{

    constructor(source) {
        this.source = source.split('');
        this.result = this.source;
    }

    subscribe(next) {
        for(let item of this.result) {
            next(item);
        }
    }

    filter(predicate) {
        this.result = this.result.filter(predicate);
        return this;
    }

    map(callback) {
        this.result = this.result.map(callback);
        return this;
    }   

}

new Observable('qwerwtyw')
    .map((letter) => { return letter.toUpperCase() })
    .filter((letter) => { return letter === 'W' })
    .subscribe((letter) => { return console.log(letter) });
```

Здесь ключевой для меня момент в том, что коллбэк, который передаётся в subscribe() вызывается каждый раз для символа "w". В данном случае 3 раза.

В angular2 получаю из сервиса список пользователей. Вот метод сервиса:

```
getUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_users/index');
}
```

А вот так этот метод используется в компоненте:

```
private allUsersData = [];
private getAllUsersData(): void {   
    this.usersService.getUsers().subscribe(
    data => {   
      this.allUsersData = JSON.parse(data);                 
      console.log('allUsersData', this.allUsersData);
    }
  )
};
```

Тут коллбэк, который передаётся в subscribe(), выполняется только один раз. Хотя в списке usres много пользователей. Мне это не понятно, поясните пожалуйста этот момент.

По моей логике коллбэк должен отрабатывать для каждого имени. то есть если с сервера прихождит массив с 10 именами, то и коллбэк выпонится 10 раз. А записан он был бы в этом случае приблизительно так:

```
.subscribe(
  data => {   
    this.allUsersData.push(data);                 
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там все правильно работает. Когда вы делаете http запрос, то вам приходит 1 результат - массив пользователей, поэтому коллбэк срабатывает 1 раз.

Comment: а если с сервера будет приходить ответ раз минуту, то каждую минуту будет запускаться этот коллбэк?

Comment: Если это будут веб сокеты, то тогда да, но это будет socket.io к примеру. А если вы хотите раз в минуту запрос делать, то на каждый запрос будет свой observable, так что нет.